# Defining namespaces in phpDoc syntax

Tags: php, phpdoc

Can anyone tell me what the correct way to define php namespaces in phpDoc syntax is? Or, is @package deprecated in phpDoc, since namespaces more or less define a package?

If there is none, is there a common way to document the namespaces a document is in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

phpDoc doesn't have a concept of namespaces but you can (and probably should) use @package for it.

You might take a look at the [phplint documentation](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phpdoc.html#namespacesandnamesresolution) to see how they're formatting namespaces.

Comment: Thank you for referencing to an existing library that uses namespace format in their documentation. I couldn't find one, definately useful!

Comment: [PHPdoc Manual](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.pkg.html) is also a good resource

Comment: Since this answer things have moved on a bit. phpDoc does now heavily use a concept of namespace but the phpDoc documentation doesn't define it as it is a PHP language concept which becomes controllable in PHP 5.3. The phpDoc documentation now recommends the use of namespaces over @package where the intent is to have the same hierarchy in both, as is often the case.

Answer (score 2):

@package Should be used in every docblock of every file in your project, you can also use @subpackage. @package is not deprecated, and would be the correct way to define your namespaces.

Comment: Thank you, @subpackage could be of use, however this doesn't solve my problem. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [DocBlox](http://docblox-project.org); this is a API Documentation Generator that supports namespaces.

And to more clearly answer your question: as far as I have encountered are packages considered Deprecated due to the invention of Namespaces.
If you read the PSR-0 specification you will see that it tries to provide the Package as second part of a namespace; first being vendor.

Answer (score 1):

The phpDoc documentation says:

> The @package tag can be used as a counterpart or supplement to
>   Namespaces. Namespaces provide a functional subdivision of Structural
>   Elements where the @package tag can provide a logical subdivision in
>   which way the elements can be grouped with a different hierarchy.
>
> If, across the board, both logical and functional subdivisions are
>   equal is it NOT RECOMMENDED to use the @package tag, to prevent
>   maintenance overhead.

https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/package.html